# How to fix header scrolling and dropdown disappearance?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, header

The header on my website works well, but for some reason the scroll-to function puts the section start behind my header instead of below it. Also, if at the top of the page, the submenu doesn't work like its supposed to and disappears. This does not happen if you are anywhere else on the page.

Thanks for your help in advance. I'm not sure where I went wrong?

For reference, my website can be found here: http://www.virtualphysio.net.
I am trying to model the style after this one https://www.paulgoughphysio.com/.

You'd think that something so simple as a nav menu wouldn't be so complicated, but this has been a thorn in my behind!

```css
/* do not change */
    .container{
    overflow: unset; 
    }
    #container ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    #container ul li ul li{
    display:none;
    }
    /* can change */
    #container{
    text-align:center;
    }
    #container ul li{
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
    border-radius:0px;
    }
    #container ul li a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    }
    #container ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
      border-radius:0px;
      color:#1dcdfe;
    }
    #container ul li:hover ul li{
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
    margin-left:0px;
    }
    #container > ul > li {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    #container > ul > li:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#scroll-home'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>About Us</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href='#scroll-whyhere'>Why You're Here</a></li>
      <li><a href='#scroll-ourmethod'>Our Method</a></li>
      <li><a href='#scroll-whyus'>Why Choose US</a></li>
          <li><a href='#scroll-testimonials'>Testimonials</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Our Services</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href='#scroll-wetreat'>What We Treat</a></li>
      <li><a href='#scroll-packages'>Packages & Pricing</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#scroll-faq'>FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That scroll will be useful when you will add more content on your website.

However, if you really want to not have those scrollbars, you can do `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: hidden` or `overflow: hidden` for both x and y axes. That will not let the child elements to expand the parent element .

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```